# how do i make item in a bucket list disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, display

I choose element div with classname item using property querySelector('.item), and expect this element to disapear when I click element a.
however it didn't work when style.display is set to none. I dont know what went wrong

```js
const minus = document.querySelector('a');
//const item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

const input = document.querySelector('input');
minus.addEventListener('click',myfunc);
function myfunc(){
    //return the display property
item.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fa {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item {
    gap: 10px;
}
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--font awe-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--bs-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--js-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <h1>Bucket list</h1>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add item</button>
        <form>
            <div class="item d-flex mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.d-flex` uses `!important` which overrides the `display: none`, It works when you remove it:

```js
const minus = document.querySelector('a');
//const item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

const input = document.querySelector('input');
minus.addEventListener('click',myfunc);
function myfunc(){
    //return the display property
    item.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fa {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item {
    gap: 10px;
}
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--font awe-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--bs-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--js-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <h1>Bucket list</h1>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add item</button>
        <form>
            <div class="item mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, instead of completely removing it you can set property `display: none` as `!important` as well so `d-flex` won't be able to override it `item.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important")`:

```js
const minus = document.querySelector('a');
//const item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const item = document.querySelector('.item');

const input = document.querySelector('input');
minus.addEventListener('click',myfunc);
function myfunc(){
    //return the display property
    item.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fa {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item {
    gap: 10px;
}
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--font awe-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--bs-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--js-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <h1>Bucket list</h1>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add item</button>
        <form>
            <div class="item d-flex mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```